# How prove that $II^{\prime}< AA^{\prime}$ for $I $ and $I^{\prime}$ be their incenters?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Assume that we have two triangles $ABC$ and  $A^{\prime}BC$. Let $I $ and $I^{\prime}$  be their incenters. How prove that $II^{\prime}< AA^{\prime}$?

I have no idea how to do this, can this be proved with simple geometry?

Comment: I find a counterexample which $ADA'<90$ so this doesn't work.

Comment: Why would it be true really?

Comment: And why not its true?